# Compile symbol not used when building via MSBUILD?

Tags: msbuild, symbols

I have a project where I have added a compile symbol (MYSYMBOL) in the project properties. When building from VS it works just fine and the application acts accordingly.

Other projects has various symbols defined this way.

When building from MSBUILD, MYSYBOL is for some strange reason ignored and the application acts as if it was never set.

I tried adding `/p:"DefineConstants=MYSYMBOL"` to the msbuild call, but then the build fails as it seems to replace the other symbols of each project with this one alone, so one assembly e.g.  requires `MYSYMBOL + OTHERSYMBOL` but now only gets `MYSYMBOL`.

This is strange since it actually does use OTHERSYMBOL for those projects that have it, when building via msbuild.

Does anyone have a clue what could be causing `MYSYMBOL` on the project properties not to be used when building via msbuild?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the build script has stated a set of compiler symbols on its own, overwriting the ones in the separate project settings which in turn caused this issue.

As far as I understand, you can't add one or more compiler symbols since anything you state replaced the symbols of the projects.

Ended up having to pass every symbol every project in the entire solution uses.

Too bad :(

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add a new symbol to the list of DefineConstants (as opposed to overriding the entire list of DefineConstants). This will do what you want:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DefineConstants>MYSYMBOL;$(DefineConstants)</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```